# Duplex scan emulation software for single side batch scanner

Tags: linux, pdf

I want scan a bunch of papers (let's say 50 pages, some double sided, some not) with my single side batch scanner and profit from a software that would (after scanning the front side batch and then (after notificating the software) the back side batch)

- at least reorder the pages automatically (front side of 1st page before back side of 1st page before front side of 2nd page, ...)
- allow multiple page scans to be saved as one (PDF, dejavu) document (basically every scan software does that)
- allow bad scans to be replaced with better scans before documents are saved without the need to rescan the whole batch
- optional auto detection of white pages and a function to remove them (best with a review function such as "jump to next blank", maybe even with learning function similar to a spam mail filter, e.g. "(un)mark page as white")
- optional auto detection of sites belonging together and function to save them as a (PDF, dejavu) document

The program should work on Linux 3.x and doesn't need to have a GUI.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for an *OpenSource* alternative, [PDFsam software](http://www.pdfsam.org/) might be your product of choice. It can merge, split and "alternate mix" PDF files to achieve the result you're looking for.

It also has an unique *Alternate Mix* feature, which you can use to "emulate" front-back scanning with a single-side home scanner such as the one I have: you can also [read this post](http://www.ryadel.com/en/scan-both-sides-of-a-front-back-document-in-a-single-pdf-with-pdfsam/) for a guide explaining how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

[pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) can do just this sort of thing nicely, including the free edition.

- Both GUI & command line available
- Free & Paid editions
- Cross Platform

Quoting from the blog:

> PDFtk has a special feature that we added specifically to solve this
>   problem of arranging scanned pages: shuffle. Say you have two PDFs:
>   even_pages.pdf and odd_pages.pdf. Then you can collate them into a
>   single document like this:
>
> pdftk A=odd_pages.pdf B=even_pages.pdf shuffle A B output
>   collated_pages.pdf
>
> If your even pages are in reverse order, you can reverse its page
>   range:
>
> pdftk A=odd_pages.pdf B=even_pages.pdf shuffle A Bend-1 output
>   collated_pages.pdf

Depending on your Linux something like:

```
sudo apt-get install pdftk
```

should install it for you.  And if you have scanned the lot into a single file it can also handle splitting the file for you.